# Android Appointments App: Flickering Issue While Reloading Data in List View

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

**Description:**

I'm developing an Android appointments app that consists of a detail view and a list view. The list view contains appointments displayed for a selected date. When I make changes in the detail view and navigate back to the list view, I want to reload the appointments for the selected date without any flickering.

**Problem:**

Currently, when reloading appointments upon selecting a new date in the list view, the screen flickers multiple times before displaying the updated data.

**Code Snippets:**

I have a ViewModel (ListVM.kt) responsible for loading appointments based on the selected date. Here are the relevant parts:

```
// ListVM.kt (ViewModel)
// ... (existing code)
private val listener = FirebaseListener<Map<String,Map<String, String>?>?> { apps ->
    _appointments.value =
        apps?.values?.mapNotNull { Appointment.fromMap(it) } ?: listOf()
}

fun loadAppointments(date: LocalDate) {
    // ... (existing code)
    AppointmentDataSource.getAppointmentsAtDate(date, listener, KEY_TO_LISTEN_WITH_LIST)
}
// ... (existing code)
```

In the ListScreen.kt, I'm using Jetpack Compose for the UI:

```
// ListScreen.kt (Jetpack Compose)
// ... (existing code)
WeekView(selectedDate, topBarActions) {
    listVM.selectedDate = it
}
// ... (existing code)
```

In the WeekCalendar.kt file, here is the relevant part:

```
// WeekCalendar.kt (Composable)
@Composable
fun WeekView(selection: LocalDate, topBarActions: @Composable() (RowScope.() -> Unit) = {}, onSelect: (LocalDate) -> Unit = {}) {
    val current = LocalDate.now()
    val startDate = remember { current.minusDays(500) }
    val endDate = remember { current.plusDays(500) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
    ) {
        val state = rememberWeekCalendarState(
            startDate = startDate,
            endDate = endDate,
            firstVisibleWeekDate = selection,
        )
        val visibleWeek = rememberFirstVisibleWeekAfterScroll(state)
        TopAppBar(
            // ... (existing code)
        )
        WeekCalendar(
            // ... (existing code)
        )
    }
}
```

**Firebase Realtime Database:**

For data storage and retrieval, I'm utilizing Firebase Realtime Database. Here's the relevant part of AppointmentDataSource.kt responsible for querying appointments based on the selected date:

```
// AppointmentDataSource.kt
private fun assignNewListener(
    query: Query,
    listener: ValueEventListener,
    key: String
) {
    listenerObserving[key]?.let { query.removeEventListener(it) }
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener)
    listenerObserving[key] = listener
}

fun getAppointmentsAtDate(
    date: LocalDate,
    listener: ValueEventListener,
    key: String
) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Requesting appointments for date ${convertDateToString(date)}")
    appointmentDBReference.orderByChild("date").equalTo(convertDateToString(date)).apply {
        assignNewListener(this, listener, key)
    }
}
```

**Steps Taken:**

To reload appointments upon selecting a new date, I've attempted two different approaches:

Using LaunchedEffect in Compose to trigger `listVM.loadAppointments(selectedDate)` when the selected date changes.
Initializing the appointment loading process in the ViewModel's init block using `selectedDate.collect { loadAppointments(it) }`.

**Expected vs. Actual Behavior:**

I expect that upon selecting a new date, the appointments for that date should reload smoothly without any flickering. However, the screen flickers multiple times before showing the updated data, making the user experience unpleasant.

**Request for Assistance:**

I'm seeking guidance on how to prevent the screen flickering issue when reloading appointments in the list view after making changes in the detail view. Any suggestions, optimizations, or alternative approaches to achieve a smoother reload of appointments based on the selected date in Jetpack Compose with Firebase Realtime Database integration would be greatly appreciated.